# Installing Sylius

Tags: php, symfony, frameworks, sylius

I am installing Sylius. In my command prompt I did

```
composer create-project -s dev sylius/sylius
```

I get this error message :

```
C:\wamp\www\Symfony>composer create-project -s dev sylius/sylius
Installing sylius/sylius (dev-master 18d981683430c0afd1a102b6fc67f8ffeaabddc0)
  - Installing sylius/sylius (dev-master master)
    Cloning master

Created project in C:\wamp\www\Symfony\sylius  
Loading composer repositories with package information  
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file  
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1  
  - Installation request for symfony/icu 1.2.x-dev -> satisfiable by symfony/icu[1.2.x-dev].
  - symfony/icu 1.2.x-dev requires lib-icu >=4.4 -> the requested linked library icu has the wrong version installed or is missing from your system, make sure to have the extension providing it.
Problem 2
  - Installation request for instaclick/php-webdriver 1.0.x-dev -> satisfiable by instaclick/php-webdriver[1.0.x-dev].
  - instaclick/php-webdriver 1.0.x-dev requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
Problem 3
  - Installation request for instaclick/php-webdriver dev-master -> satisfiable by instaclick/php-webdriver[dev-master].
  - instaclick/php-webdriver dev-master requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
Problem 4
  - symfony/icu 1.2.x-dev requires lib-icu >=4.4 -> the requested linked library icu has the wrong version installed or is missing from your system, make sure to have the extension providing it.
  - symfony/symfony 2.3.x-dev requires symfony/icu ~1.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/icu[1.2.x-dev].
  - Installation request for symfony/symfony 2.3.x-dev -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[2.3.x-dev].
```

What I tried :

1. `php composer.phar self update`
2. `php composer.phar install`
3. Deleting sylius directory
4. Reinstalling sylius with the create-project command
5. Fresh installation of Symfony 2.3.4 and reinstallation of sylius
6. Did what was told in the first answer: enable extension curl and intl
7. Used the function get_loaded_extension() to confirm that curl and intl are loaded. Well, it is loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WAMP has two `php.ini` files, one for apache and one for CLI. When you click on WAMP tray icon in php modules you can see only modules enabled for apache, and so enabling and disabling modules takes effect only for apache copy of `php.ini`.

Try enabling `curl` and `intl` in `X:\path\to\wamp\bin\php\php.ini` which is config for CLI (BTW. config for apache is placed in `X:\path\to\wamp\bin\apache\bin\php.ini`).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to install two PHP extensions to make this work: `curl` and `intl` (which provides the lib-icu required by symfony/icu). Since you are using Windows, I recommend the [official guide](http://php.net/manual/de/install.windows.extensions.php) on how to install extensions on Windows systems. You can find the `intl` extension in the PECL repository [here](http://pecl.php.net/package/intl).

`curl` should be installed on your WAMP already, but disabled by default. See the top answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13021536/how-to-enable-curl-in-wamp-server) for instructions on how to enable it.

Comment: Thanks, Working it out

Comment: Still the same problem.

Comment: If you run `php -i`, it should show you a (long) list of the active PHP extensions. Are `curl` and `intl` in that list?

Comment: i did php -i and redirect the output in a text file, then did a search for intl and curl.  Result --> " Cannot find curl" and also intl. 

intl and curl both have a tick in Wamp Server

Comment: If they are not shown as enabled in the `php -i` output, they are not active. Unfortunately I am not that familiar with Wamp Server, so I don't think I can help you with fixing that; you could try asking for help on the official forums (http://forum.wampserver.com/list.php?2).

Comment: @UmeirHussy take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16753105/problems-with-lib-icu-dependency-when-installing-symfony-2-3-x-via-composer. It's a similar problem with the lib-icu.

Answer (score 0):

Sylius has now released the latest version v1.0.0 which I have covered in a blog to install it. Here is the Source: https://www.cloudways.com/blog/install-sylius-ecommerce-framework/

You just need to run the following cammands in SSH or Terminal Sylius will be installed

- `$ composer create-project -s beta sylius/sylius-standard project`
- `$ cd project`
- `$ npm install`
- `$ npm run gulp`
- `$ bin/console sylius:install`