# intl and icu configuration

Tags: symfony, icu, whm, intl

I've been working on a local development machine running Ubuntu 12 developing a `Symfony2.3.5` application.

All works well, until I uploaded the code and came across this:

```
Could not load the resource bundle "/home/project/public_html/vendor/symfony/icu/Symfony/Component/Icu/Resources/data/region/en.res".
```

The server is currently running the following:

```
CENTOS 5.9 x86_64 standard WHM 11.38.2 (build 7)
```

In WHM I've installed `intl` via the EasyApache installer, yet I'm still getting this error.

This installed `ICU 3.6`. My development version is 4.8.1, so about 10 years newer.

Is the ICU version the problem here? It's the only thing I can see.

The application I've built is `en-only`. It does not need to be in any other language other than English (UK).

Does anyone have any ideas / fixes for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Symfony 2.3 requires the intl extension to be version `>= 4.0` ( a version greater than `4.4` at best ) because of it's dependency to the `symfony/intl` component.

Composer will download different versions of `symfony/intl` and lock these in your `composer.lock` depending on your development ICU version.

This means if you develop on a system with ICU greater than 4.4 you won't be able to install on a server with ICU < 4.4.

Please read the documentation chapter [ICU and Deployment Problems](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/intl.html).

Update your intl extension as suggested in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16753105/problems-with-lib-icu-dependency-when-installing-symfony-2-3-x-via-composer):

```
sudo aptitude install php5-intl
```

... or add

```
"require: {
    "symfony/icu": "1.0.*"
}
```

to your `composer.json`.

Comment: I'll upgrade my ICU version and give it a go!

Answer (score 0):

For me worked installing symfony/intl

```
"symfony/intl": "2.5.5",

php composer.phar update symfony/intl
```