# Could not load the resource bundle /en_US_POSIX.res"

Tags: symfony, icu, intl

After deploying my Symfony 2.4 web application, I have a page where it calls to a FormType with a field type `country`.

```
$builder->add('pays', 'country');
```

However, it crashes and I get this error:

> `Could not load the resource bundle "/var/www/vhosts/my_website.com/httpdocs/vendor/symfony/icu/Symfony/Component/Icu/Resources/data/region/en_US_POSIX.res`

I tried to add the file `en_US_POSIX.res` but it still not working.

I have the following setup.

- PHP Version 5.3.3
- Intl version 1.1.0
- ICU version 3.6

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should have a version of `intl` > 4.0.

see this answer it may help you [intl and icu configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19098455/intl-and-icu-configuration)