# Problems with Intl extension

Tags: php, symfony, intl

I'm really struggling with this..

I'm developing a cms web application, using Symfony. I have installed a few cms bundles just to test. But in all of them get the error:

**Please install the "intl" extension for full localization capabilities.**

This is very strange, because I have Intl libraries already installed. By the terminal I can see that "*icu4c-52.1 already installed*". I dont understand, am I missing anything.. I'm using MacOS 10.8.3, is there a compatibility issue, or some missing configuration?

Thanks for you help.

Comment: Maybe a version issue? Did you check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19098455/intl-and-icu-configuration)?

Comment: I dont know how to do this on a MAC but in windows you either have to copy the icu* files from the PHP folder to the apache/bin folder or create symlinks in the apache/bin folder to the icu* files in the PHP folder. So I guess you have to do something similiar but MACify it.

Comment: in terminal type " php -i | grep php.ini"  and check if your PATH php points to the correct bin directory, sound like its not

Comment: What are you using for the web server? OSX has PHP installed so when you are using `php app/console` or just `app/console` it would be using OSX's version and the when you browse it would (if you using MAMP, for example) be using `/Applications/MAMP/bin/...`.

Comment: @john Smith, its pointing to the right place.

Comment: @Qoop I have tried MAMP, and i had some problems, now I using XAMPP. And I think thats the problem, but how do I use only the right path?

Comment: @Johnny so your php.ini is located at /Applications/XAMPP/bin/php/php5.x/conf/php.ini  ?

Comment: @john Smith mine is pointing to /private/etc/php.ini, how do I change to that path?