# Problems installing Symfony 2.4.1 lib-icu 4.4 dependency

Tags: php, symfony, pear, pecl, icu

I'm having a problem identical to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16753105/problems-with-lib-icu-dependency-when-installing-symfony-2-3-x-via-composer), but the solution provided there isn't working for me.

I downloaded the Symfony 2.4.1 Standard Vendors with Vendors package from [the Symfony Downloads Page](http://symfony.com/download). After extracting the files and downloading composer.phar, I run `php composer.phar install` and get this error:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - symfony/icu v1.2.0 requires lib-icu >=4.4 -> the requested linked library icu has the wrong version installed or is missing from your system, make sure to have the extension providing it.
    - symfony/icu v1.2.0 requires lib-icu >=4.4 -> the requested linked library icu has the wrong version installed or is missing from your system, make sure to have the extension providing it.
    - Installation request for symfony/icu v1.2.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/icu[v1.2.0].
```

Following the instructions on the thread linked to above, I updated PEAR libraries and did `sudo pear install pecl/intl`. (This is on CentOS so I didn't follow the MAMP stuff). This didn't work and I realized I had to do a `sudo yum install libicu`. After this, `sudo pear install pecl/intl` worked, and I edited `php.ini` to add the `extension=intl.so` line and then restarted the Apache server.

But I'm still getting the same error as above, and in addition, any time I run PHP it gives the warning:

```
PHP Warning:  Module 'intl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
```

Looking at the output of `phpinfo()` I see that the installed intl version is 1.1.0, and the ICU version is `4.2.1` (which explains why Symfony is complaining that it needs 4.4). But when I do `/usr/bin/pecl install intl` it says

```
pecl/intl is already installed and is the same as the released version 3.0.0
```

And the `sudo yum install libicu` should have installed the latest version.

Is there any way to get the 4.4 version?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For your specific situation, you should specify in your composer.json file that you want to use "symfony/icu": "1.1.*"

See the "ICU and Deployment Problems" section of this page: https://symfony.com/doc/2.4/components/intl.html

Comment: Thanks, that page helped.

Comment: Apologies if this is not the place for this feedback, but I couldn't find anywhere else to put it.  It was suggested that the link be updated to the current documentation, which I would normally agree with, but in this case the problem is specific to a certain symfony range (These deployment problems only affect the following Symfony versions: 2.3.0 to 2.3.20 versions, any 2.4.x version and 2.5.0 to 2.5.5 versions) and does not apply to "current".  If you go to the "current" version for the docs the "ICU and Deployment Problems" mentioned in this answer is not present.

Comment: Here's the original link which includes the explanation for why this solution works: https://symfony.com/doc/2.4/components/intl.html

Answer (score 0):

you are editing the wrong php.ini file

run this command in console :

> php -i | grep php.ini
>
> ```
> Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc/php5/cli
> Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
> ```

edit that file.  ( it's the php cli file )

Comment: There's no `/etc/php5` directory. There is `/etc/php.ini` (the file I edited) and a `/etc/php.d` directory which contains these files: `curl.ini        fileinfo.ini    json.ini        mysqli.ini      pdo.ini         pdo_sqlite.ini  sqlite3.ini     xmlreader.ini   xsl.ini
dom.ini         intl.ini        mbstring.ini    mysql.ini       pdo_mysql.ini   phar.ini        wddx.ini        xmlwriter.ini   zip.ini`

The command you said to run gives this: `Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php.ini`