# Getting error symfony2 fos message bundle installation

Tags: php, symfony

I am getting error when i install fos message bundle in my project.
I will get this error

`"Installation request for symfony/icu == 1.2.2.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/icu[v1.2.2].
- symfony/icu v1.2.2 requires lib-icu >=4.4 -> the requested linked library
icu has the wrong version installed or is missing from your system, make sure to
 have the extension providing it."`

My `composer.json` code:

```
{
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "": "src/", "SymfonyStandard": "app/" }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.5.*",
        "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2",
        "twig/extensions": "~1.0",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~3.0",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
        "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "SymfonyStandard\\Composer::hookRootPackageInstall"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::removeSymfonyStandardFiles"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::removeSymfonyStandardFiles"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin"
    },

    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
        },
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "2.5-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: geeting error when install fos message bundle in symfony2 through composer

    [RuntimeException]Failed to execute git status --porcelain --untracked-files=no 'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.
    
    require [--dev] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--no-progress] [--no-update]
    [--update-no-dev] [--update-with-dependencies] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--sort-
    packages] [packages1] ... [packagesN]

Answer (score 1):

Solution to your problem you can find reading the post:

[Problems with lib-icu dependency when installing Symfony 2.3.x via Composer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16753105/problems-with-lib-icu-dependency-when-installing-symfony-2-3-x-via-composer)

You need to install a special php library php5-intl
You can do that using:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-intl
```

for Ubuntu/Debian users

Comment: i am windows user so please specify the code for that

Comment: For windows users checkout:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451468/intl-extension-installing-php-intl-dll

Comment: Alternatively you can use `"symfony/icu": "1.0.*"` if you can't install it at all. Details are in the "ICU and Deployment Problems" section on the docs page - http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/intl.html .

Comment: geeting error  again through composer

    [RuntimeException]Failed to execute git status --porcelain --untracked-files=no 'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.
    
    require [--dev] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--no-progress] [--no-update]
    [--update-no-dev] [--update-with-dependencies] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--sort-
    packages] [packages1] ... [packagesN]