# Issue regarding Symfony/icu

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.3

I am new in Symfony. I got a project from my client which is previously developed. I tried to install in my localhost.In this regard I got following error

```
Fatal error: Class 'FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle' not found in D:\php\htdocs\my_project\app\AppKernel.php on line 22
```

Then I tried to update `friendsofsymfony /user-bundle` and  got following result

```
D:\php\htdocs\my_project>php D:\php\php\composer.phar update friendsofsymfony /user-bundle Loading composer repositories with package information Updating dependencies (including require-dev) Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1

symfony/icu v1.2.0 requires lib-icu >=4.4 -> the requested linked library icu has the wrong version installed or is missing from your system, make sure to have the extension providing it.

symfony/icu v1.2.0 requires lib-icu >=4.4 -> the requested linked library icu has the wrong version installed or is missing from your system, make sure to have the extension providing it.

symfony/icu v1.2.0 requires lib-icu >=4.4 -> the requested linked library icu has the wrong version installed or is missing from your system, make sure to have the extension providing it.

Installation request for symfony/icu == 1.2.0.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/ icu[v1.2.0].
```

Then I read this post ([Problems with lib-icu dependency when installing Symfony 2.3.x via Composer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16753105/problems-with-lib-icu-dependency-when-installing-symfony-2-3-x-via-composer)) and tried to follow instruction to update `Symfony/icu` and got following result

```
D:\php\htdocs\my_project>php D:\php\php\composer.phar update symfony/icu
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Removing symfony/icu (v1.0.1)
  - Installing symfony/icu (v1.1.2)
    Downloading: 100%

  - Updating knplabs/doctrine-behaviors dev-master (c78fbb4 => ea0f040)
    The package has modified files:
    D ihadis/app/Resources/assets/plugins/bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-r
egular.eot?
    Discard changes [y,n,v,s,?]? n



  [RuntimeException]
  Update aborted



update [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--lock]
 [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-
progress] [--with-dependencies] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader]
 [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [packages1] ... [p
ackagesN]
```

How can I update `Symfony/icu` and `friendsofsymfony/user-bundle` ??Could anyone give me solution in this regard ??

Comment: Have you enabled icu in your PHP environment? It depends of your Web server (WAMP, EasyPHP, etc.).

Comment: Thanks  @A.L for your quick response. Yes, I enabled icu in my PHP environment (php.ini file).
I removed comment from this line (in php.ini):

`extension=php_intl.dll`

Comment: Did you enabled `ICU` in CLI (command line) environment? Do you see `ICU` with [`php -m`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/478922/2257664)?

Comment: Thanks @A.L for your reply. I am getting this

`D:\php\htdocs\my_project>php -m
[PHP Modules]
bcmath
bz2
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
ereg
exif
filter
ftp
gd
gettext
hash
iconv
intl
json
libxml
mbstring
mcrypt
mhash
mysql
mysqli
mysqlnd
odbc
openssl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
pdo_sqlite
Phar
Reflection
session
SimpleXML
soap
sockets
SPL
sqlite3
standard
tokenizer
wddx
xml
xmlreader
xmlrpc
xmlwriter
xsl
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]`

Comment: Ok, `intl` is installed so `ICU` should be available. I'm sorry I don't know how to help you.

Comment: Thanks @A.L for your effort. Could you please attract attention of someone who is more expert in this regard??

Comment: Why did you aborted the composer installation? What if you install all the requested packages?

Comment: Actually I first tired with **y** command and then tried with **n** command.

Comment: According to the code in your question you refused (you chose `n`) to install the dependencies, so it's hard to help you.

Comment: I chose **y** before this code execution.First I tired with y command and then tried with n command.